# How to optimise editable content for website with php include?

Tags: php, include

I got a problem and it was hard to formulate the question in a simple manner.

Im making website, and i want to optimise it to have less server requests, and for website to stay flexible in editing manner:
* where i could some "rarely editable content" (logo, menu, background,footer, etc.)
* and some other content that will be editable very often (text areas, galleries and more)

I was thinking about making all this in small php peaces and then use php include. The problem is that i will have to create a lot of small files. And it would be a lot of server requests, and a lot of hassle when website will have more and more files.

Is there a better way to manage websites "rarely editable" and normal content?

If no, maybe can i somehow combine at least "rarely editable" content in one file? like header, menu and footer? And use it with one include?

Im not good at php but i think i would manage it if the answer would be nice :)

Comment: Using `include()` doesn't add to the number of server requests; it adds a little bit in server resources though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "include" or "require" in a php script does not produce server requests. It only works on filesystem level.
If you use one file i.e. "index.php" and include the rest in that script, you will only have one request from the client (except images, javascript etc. of course).